# Can an iPhone app developed in Flash CS5 communicate with an external server?

Tags: ios, flash, flash-cs5

With normal Flash SWF's I use URLRequest to communicate with external servers/sites to send/retreive data from a database - pretty standard stuff.

But can iPhone apps published from the CS5 environment communicate with external servers/sites?

I'm still organising my development license for the iphone, so want to check before I fork out the money for the registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use all the same networking APIs. (The main thing that doesn't work on iOS is loading SWF files that contain ActionScript.)

Comment: I'm not sure that is correct - the SWF loading ActionScript part. If the flash file is published out to an IPA it will work if it contains ActionScript or not.

Comment: If it is part of the IPA, then you aren't loading it (and technically, it isn't even a SWF file anymore).

Comment: Yes exactly - so a SWF (regardless if it contains actionscript or not) won't run. But as stated in the original question, an app published from CS5 (which is an ipa file) - can that communicate with an external server?